# How to find the row index of a specific string within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I would like some help finding the row index, so I know what row number in a Google Sheet has a specific string value entered as a note.
I have the code below which works fine for a range with one column, but as I expand the range to say 30 columns and multiple rows the position does not correspond to the row.
I'm looking for some help to modify this so I can find the string in any given cell within the expanded range (which preferably covers all sheet cells with data in the cells).
I'm trying to learn, arrays are powerful, and I do not understand how to use them for these types of operations.

```
 var sheetName = 'Form Responses';    
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);   
 var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();  
 var lastCol = sh.getLastColumn();
 var data = sh.getRange(1, 30, lastRow).getNotes().toString();

        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            var row = data.indexOf("Responder updated this value.");
            var intRow = row + 1;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't use the `.getRange()` correct.
Try this:

```
var data = sh.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastCol).getNotes();
var row = -1;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  if(data[i].indexOf("Responder updated this value.") != -1){
    row = i + 1;
    break;
  }
}
```